# symfony3 :how to convert xml routing file to yml

Tags: symfony

i just integrate fos_user Bundle , and this latter use xml routing file ! i want to know if there is a command or somthing to convert it to yml file

Answer (score 1):

You can use this online tool :

http://converter.rosstuck.com/

You can also install and use [this](https://github.com/rosstuck/TuckConverterBundle) bundle which provides a command to do this :

```
app/console container:convert yml path/to/file.xml
```

Comment: when i try to install TuckConverterBundle by using this command : composer require tuck/converter-bundle and i obtain : installation failed reverting ./composer.json to its original content

Comment: if you had this line : `"tuck/converter-bundle": "dev-master"` in your composer.json and then execute this command : `app/console composer update tuck/converter-bundle` ?

Comment: Installation request for symfony/symfony (locked at v3.1.3, required as 3.1.*) -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.1.3].

Comment: huuum it is possible that this bundle cant be used for Symfony >= 3.*

Comment: when i use http://converter.rosstuck.com/  it does'y work when i put :   <route id="fos_user_registration_register" path="/" methods="GET POST">
        <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Registration:register</default>
    </route>    what should i put ?

Comment: i just read this article by changing the header but it does't convert :/